# How should you ask a question where multiple correct answers are most likely and preferred?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, community-wiki

How should you ask a question where the aim is to collate multiple peoples expertise on one subject matter rather than a pure question answer set up. For example:

What ways have people modelled evapotranspiration using satellite data? I have found x,y,z but want to know if there are any additional methodologies.

I know you can use community wiki when answering a question, but not sure what the format should be where one answer will most likely only ever form part of the overall answer.

Comment: Such questions are usually primarily opinion-based and don't fit with our model.

Comment: “How should you ask a question where the aim is to collate multiple peoples expertise on one subject matter rather than a pure question answer set up.” - You don’t ask it.  Such a question would be flagged by most experienced StackExchange reviewers

Answer (score 1):

I think that a question such as this sounds like the antithesis of focused Q&A and should be closed as too broad on most Stack Exchange sites.

For focused Q&A there should be a single answer sought with multiple answers offered and voted upon to try and uncover which is the best candidate for that answer.